# How can I get the name of the alternative in an active Google Optimize test from the console?

Tags: google-optimize

How can I get the name of the alternative in an active Google Optimize test from the console?

I need it for SessionCam recording of multiple variants.

I tried with public variables setted in tests, but the original variant can't be edited like in Adobe Target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no doc about getting the name of the alternative in an active Google Optimize test, but SessionCam can be filtered by test alternatives inserting this "BETA" snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!window.sessioncamConfiguration)
        window.sessioncamConfiguration = new Object();
    if(!window.sessioncamConfiguration.customDataObjects)
        window.sessioncamConfiguration.customDataObjects = [];
    var item = { key: "GoogleOptimise", value: "testName" };
    window.sessioncamConfiguration.customDataObjects.push(item);
</script>
```

Then can be filtered in SessionCam with a Segment which has a filter reading "Field Value" for "GoogleOptimise" is "Entered".